# how to avoid auto session create in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I've been trying to work with sessions using Codeigniter, still I found out everytime I refresh the browser a new session is created... which makes no sense. I try to delete all sessions and then I get a new one, has anyone seen this error??

this is my code:

```
$this->load->library('session');
print_r  ($this->session->all_userdata());
$this->session->sess_destroy();
```

So, with the sess_destroy I delete the session, but when I refresh the site a new session comes..

Comment: if you echo out the session_id() does it return the same id or a different one each time you reload?

Comment: its a different id everytime... like if would be creating a new one everytime I refresh the browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is a default and normal behavior. Consult "How do Sessions work?" section in the [Session Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) chapter of the CodeIgniter User Guide. It says:

> If sessions data does **not** exist (or if it has expired) a new session will be created and saved in the cookie.

This is provided the Session class has been initiated before, using

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

what is exactly the case here.

If you're concerned about the security, don't worry. The new session does not carry over the previous session's data.

Finally, if for some reason you want to destroy the session and initiate it conditionally, check if it exists with:

```
if($this->session->userdata('username') === FALSE )
```

As stated in the manual:

> **Note**: The function returns FALSE (boolean) if the item you are trying to access does not exist.

Comment: you are right!! but I found the problem in my config file, for some reason if I had sess_encrypt_cookie set on false, the session just didnt work.

Answer (score 2):

Umm, pretty sure sess_destroy destroys the old session, so of course you'll get a new one upon refresh!

EDIT:

Confirmed after a quick peak at Session.php

```
/**
 * Destroy the current session
 *
 * @access  public
 * @return  void
 */
function sess_destroy()
```

Comment: That is to say simply remove `$this->session->sess_destroy();` from your code unless there's a specific reason you need to nuke it at some point.

Comment: Well, I deleted the sess_destroy... but still... I get a session with no username... is it normal??? I get something like this Array ( [session_id] => 0cc6979e239bd106afb00be2743a6604 [ip_address] => 127.0.0.1 [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1 FirePHP/0.7.1 [last_activity] => 1341947927 [user_data] => )

Comment: You have to put the username in there yourself, it's not there by default.  $_SESSION['username'] = 'bob';